# Como saber quando a query do SQLite terminou?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, web-service, sqlite, retrofit

No meu app tenho um método de sincronização, este método faz o download de vários cadastros do meu webservice e os insere no banco de dados SQLite local através de um loop for.
Preciso saber quando o a inserção do SQLite acabou para poder exibir uma janela informando que a operação foi realizada com sucesso.

Porém, são muitos cadastros, mais de 500, e o SQLite acaba levando alguns segundos para fazer a inserção no banco de dados, e com esses segundos que demoram, meu código já realiza a chamada da AlerDialog informando o resultado da operação.

Como posso fazer com que a AlertDialog só seja chamada quando a inserção do SQLite estiver completamente finalizada?

Chamada do retrofit que realiza o download dos cadastros

```
final CadastroApi cadastroApi = retrofit.create(CadastroApi.class);

Call<List<Cadastro>> callCadastro = cadastroApi.getCadastro(token);
    callCadastro.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cadastro>>() {
        @Override
         public void onResponse(Response<List<Cadastro>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            List<Cadastro> cadastroList = response.body();

            if (cadastroList != null) {

                try {

                    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(TokenActivity.this, token);
                    SQLiteDatabase conn = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    RepositorioCadastro repositorioCadastro = new RepositorioCadastro(conn);

                    // Insere cada item da lista no Banco de dados
                        for (Cadastro c : cadastroList) {

                            repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(c);

                            Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Cadastro inserido ID: " + c.getId());

                        }

                } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                 Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Erro ao inserir Cadastro(s) no banco de dados local: " + e.getMessage());
                }

}
```

Comment: Beleza Rafael? você poderia usar uma AsyncTask e só disparar esse cara quando a query estiver completa, para não dar a sensação de que o app travou você poderia ter um loader até terminar a operacão.

Comment: Bom , eu já possuo um loader, ele aparece no momento em que o usuário clica no botão sincronizar. Acontece que eu possuo mais 3 tabelas no banco de dados que são atualizadas ao mesmo tempo, cada uma em uma chamada do diferente do retrofit, se eu coloco uma asyncTask para cada uma das operações, o app dropa muitos frames, por volta de 500...

Comment: Essa atualização em conjunto é realmente necessária?

Comment: Como assim? Realizar todas as operações ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: isso, esses dados precisam estar em tabelas diferentes?